# UILabel alignment: show "..." at the end

Tags: iphone, uilabel

In my app I am assigning fixed width and height to uilabel and assigning some text to it. My problem is if the text length is more than the label height I want to show "..." at the end of the text eg "apple... " . Is there is any property to show like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, please check the line break property and set it to truncateTail

`label.lineBrakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;`

Comment: The default lineBreakMode itself is UILineBreakModeTailTruncation right?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 40); //to keep height fixed to 40 //or use (150,300) to keep width fixed to 150 and varying height .  
    NSString *myString =@"Text for lable";
    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"marker felt" size:14];// font used for label
    CGSize myStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont 
                               constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                                   lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
```

use MySTringSize to set the frame for label. And use nemberOfLines property for label, it might be helpfull.